# Error con objeto Container en Flet

Tags: python, python-3.x, flet

estoy aprendiendo a usar la librería flet para python y estoy teniendo un error con un widget. El widget es de tipo Container, dejo una versión reproducible de mi código aquí:

```
import flet as ft

class App():
    def __init__(self, page:ft.Page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page=page
        self.page.window_height=altura_base_ventana
        self.page.window_width=ancho_base_ventana
        self.page.bgcolor=ft.colors.INDIGO_400
        
        
        self.mensaje_error=ft.Container(bgcolor=ft.colors.with_opacity(color=ft.colors.PINK, opacity=0.1),
                                                height=altura_base_entrada,
                                                content=content=ft.Row(
                                                    ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.DANGEROUS, color=ft.colors.RED), 
                                                    ft.Text(value='Datos incorrectos. Por favor inténtelo de nuevo', 
                                                            size=10, 
                                                            font_family='poppins regular', 
                                                            color=ft.colors.RED)
                                                    
                                        ))
        
        self.page.add(self.mensaje_error)

ft.app(target=App)
```

Modifiqué el código para que el control no fuese un arreglo, pero ahora me salta el error: TypeError: `'Icon' object is not iterable`

Si alguien pudiera decirme que estoy haciendo mal se los agradezco

Comment: ¿Por qué el _content_ de tu `Container` es un array?

Comment: @padaleiana Hola, lo puse entre paréntesis y ahora me salta el error que dice en la pregunta. Y este si no me hace sentido, porque los widgets se declaran asi.

Answer (score 0):

El argumento `controls` del constructor de `Row` tiene que ser un iterable con los widgets hijos a mostrar distribuidos horizontalmente. Aunque en realidad cualquier iterable seria valido, concretamente debería ser una lista de objetos `Control` (`flet.control.Control`), si [seguimos la declaración de tipos](https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/blob/8d11acecade5417dc84ae063a7ebd0d74f490d68/sdk/python/flet/row.py#L19):

```
class Row(ConstrainedControl):
    def __init__(
        self,
        controls: List[Control] = None,
        ref: Ref = None,
        ...
```

En tu caso le estas pasando un objeto `Icon` a dicho argumento, como espera un iterable intenta iterar sobre el para obtener cada uno de los widgets hijos a mostrar y ahí salta la excepción, porque `Icon` no es un objeto iterable, lo mismo que no lo es por ejemplo `int`:

> ```
> >>> for item in 1234:
> ...     print(item)
> ... 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Mientras que una lista de enteros si que lo es:

> ```
> >>> for item in [1, 2, 3]:
> ...     print(item)
> ...
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```

En definitiva, que al argumento `controls` le debes pasar una lista porque eso es lo que espera:

```
    self.mensaje_error = ft.Container(
        bgcolor=ft.colors.with_opacity(color=ft.colors.PINK, opacity=0.1),
        height=200,
        content=ft.Row(
            [ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.DANGEROUS, color=ft.colors.RED),
             ft.Text(
                 value='Datos incorrectos. Por favor inténtelo de nuevo',
                 size=10,
                 font_family='poppins regular',
                 color=ft.colors.RED)
             ]
        ))
```

como mucho te aceptara otro iterable como una tupla, un generador, un conjunto, etc. Por ejemplo, una tupla también funcionara aunque si chequeas tipos con *mypy* señalara que el tipo es incorrecto:

```
    self.mensaje_error = ft.Container(
        bgcolor=ft.colors.with_opacity(color=ft.colors.PINK, opacity=0.1),
        height=200,
        content=ft.Row(
            (ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.DANGEROUS, color=ft.colors.RED),
             ft.Text(
                 value='Datos incorrectos. Por favor inténtelo de nuevo',
                 size=10,
                 font_family='poppins regular',
                 color=ft.colors.RED)
             )
        ))
```

Por cierto, no confundas los paréntesis usados para llamar a una función/método o a una clase como en este caso (`Row`), con los paréntesis que se usan para definir una tupla o un generador (generadores por compresión). Observa que no es lo mismo:

```
content=ft.Row((ft.Icon(...), ft.Text()))
              ^^                       ^^
              ||________ Tupla ________||
              |__ Llamada a clase Row __|
```

que aunque no sea una lista es valido, y que equivalente a:

```
content=ft.Row(controls=(ft.Icon(...), ft.Text()))
```

que:

```
content=ft.Row(ft.Icon(...), ft.Text(...))
```

que equivale a:

```
content=ft.Row(controls=ft.Icon(...), ref=ft.Text(...))
```

lo que es totalmente incorrecto.